# Перевод android приложения через google translate

Tags: android, локализация, google-translate

Вручную переводить strings.xml - мазохизм (столько языков!!,столько слов!!).

Есть какие-нибудь автоматизированные решения? Т.е.:

> 1. Я даю strings.xml на английском
> 2. Эта штука переводит его (используя google translate) на все языки, поддерживаемые google translate и создаёт папки (values-de и др.) и туда кидает переведённый strings.xml.

Comment: >Вручную переводить strings.xml - мазохизм

Однако это единственный правильный подход.

Comment: @klopp под вручную я имел ввиду:

1. открыть strings.xml
2. увидеть:

     <string name="fldesc">It\'s the most popular model with high speed</string>

3. Скопировать It's the most popular model with high speed в google translate 
4. Получить E 'il modello più popolare con l'alta velocità
5. Создать values-it, в нём создать string.xml и вставить <string name="fldesc">E \'il modello più popolare con l\'alta velocità</string>

Comment: А я другое :) Открыть ресурсы, найти строку. Загрузить приложение, посмотреть в каком контексте и в каком интерфейсном окружении она появляется. Перевести собственной головой, повторить всё с новым языком, проверить. И так - по каждой строке. Серьёзно, всё остальное  "гуртовщики мыши" и халтура. Ну а если хочется халтуры, то нужно искать переводчики с API (у гугла оно платное, но тут от потребностей звисит, может `$20 per 1 M characters of text` и немного). Распарсить xml, скормить api, собрать новый xml.

Comment: @klopp это понятно. Просто не все языки в мире выучишь :). А вот начёт *Распарсить xml, скормить api, собрать новый xml.* - это то что я ищу. Конечно можно написать самому, но придётся повозиться. Да и лень как всегда протестует...

Comment: Что-то поковырялся - бесплатных api не нашёл. Можно подробней посмотреть, например:

http://gengo.com/api/

http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=12&WSID=63

Но с автопереводом всё равно куча глюков, достаточно посмотреть на машинный перевод описаний в том же гуглплее - обхохочешься. Плюс неочевидные трудности, например, с немецким...

В общем, найдётся api - посмотрим как автоматизировать, надо уже от известного отталкиваться.

Comment: @klopp можно пойти по подпольному:

http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=ru&sl=en&tl=ru&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1&q=something

Возвращает - http://pastebin.com/FJKeYmHJ

Comment: Нужно разбираться с HTTP-заголовками, простые запросы роботом (LWP, curl, wget и т.д.) не проходят, 403.

Comment: Fiddler так прошёл:

![alt text][1]

Будем копировать


  [1]: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62250661/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B92.png

Comment: @klopp предлагая совместными усилиями написать такую штуку! Распарсить ее не должно составить большого труда: SAX. Работа с АПИ гугл не так сложна! Может сделаем?

Comment: Да я уже набросал за 3 минуты на коленке, работа такая, фактически копипаст пары готовых кусков :) Но - Perl.
(нафига мучиться и писать подобные парсеры на чём-то ещё для меня загадка...)

Comment: Можешь прислать потестить? У меня самого часто появляется нужда перевода!

Comment: ой не нужно такое писать. Даже при переводе между родными и близкими (как некоторым кажется) языками как украинский и русский, вылазят такие бока... Даже когда переводят профессиональные переводчики, все равно иногда бывают проколы. Потом нужно ещё смотреть, как оно будет на результирующем интерфейсе.

Comment: >Даже при переводе между родными и близкими (как некоторым кажется) языками как украинский и русский, вылазят такие бока..

О чём я и говорил с самого начала :) А как выглядит в интерфейсе наглядно демонстрируют попытки работать с немецким...

Comment: @vanyamelikov, это ж задачка простейшая. Что там писать? Можно даже рассматривать в качестве упражнения :) Но не более того.

Comment: @vanyamelikov я сам её напишу. Задачка лёгкая. Сроки - не больше недели. Язык: java. Особенности: open source

Comment: Парсер готов:

  texto.delete(0, 3);

  texto.delete(texto.indexOf("\""), -1);

Comment: Это все понятно! Но от парсера до полноценной программы перевода не малый путь. Максимализм приветствуется. По хорошему надо согласовать это дело с АПИ какого нить проффесионального переводчика.

Comment: Наприме c API Trados. Забить в начале повторяющиеся термины, создание собственной базы переводов и т.д. чтобы получался не бред а более менее понятный перевод!

Comment: [http://translate.google.com/toolkit/](http://translate.google.com/toolkit/)

Comment: @falstaf пол беды облегчает. Но языков, поддерживаемых гоголем over9000. Вручную выбирать каждый язык и скачивать под него подходящий файл тоже не фонтан

Comment: >пол беды облегчает

Наоборот, новые беды создаёт :) Поверьте человеку, не одну собаку съевшему на локализациях. Переделывать автоматический перевод - это сложней, чем переводить сразу.

Comment: @klopp так это, если я ни одного немецкого слова не знаю, а немцы хотят хоть какой-то перевод, то что делать. А при переводе своего приложения на русский (дааа, я на инглише изначально всё делал) я в google translate ни разу не забегал

Comment: Кинуть клич среди знакомых, в студенческих средах, наскрести копеечку и жалостно просить фрилансеров... Всё что угодно, только не машинный перевод. Он может рассмешить заказчика в лучшем случае, а скорее всего - хуже, до оскорбления и потери доверия к исполнителю. Если вы не знаете языка, то и не поймёте, сколько ляпов было, до полного искажения смысла самых простых фраз.
Да и заказчика можно попросить помочь. В форме "я сомневаюсь, правильно ли это", и под этим предлогом подсовывать варианты для проверки :) Это не признание своей несостоятельности, а партнёрский подход, это всегда ценится.

Comment: @klopp я не только разработчик, но ещё и заказчик. Т.е. работаю от своего имени. Да и приложение у меня такое, что стоимость перевода может оказаться больше, чем заработок. И останусь я в минусе. Короче, моё приложение - как делать бумажные самолётики

Comment: Так в данном случае "заказчик" - ваши юзеры! Ну так найдите кого-нибудь из потенциальных юзеров, им тем более интересно будет принять участие в процессе :) В общем, творчески подходить надо, это тоже часть разработки :) Я не могу, понятное дело, дать универсального совета, кроме одного: машинного перевода нужно избезать всеми способами, лучше вообще никакого (нейтральный английский сгодится даже для таких англофобов как французы), чем он. Это аксиома.

Comment: @klopp тогда можно скинуть на http://www.getlocalization.com/signup/ . Стоик копейку, удобный интерфейс. И всё-таки для языков без добровольцев лучше google translate как-никак

Comment: Вы почему-то не хотите понимать простой вещи: не лучше, а хуже. Лучше никакого перевода или английский, чем машинный. Не буду пробивать лбом бетонную стену, упорствуйте в своих заблуждениях дальше :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нормальные переводчики используют [Trados](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trados) или нечто подобное, он большинство текста переводит по базе переводов, а остальное отдает переводчику. Традос умеет правильно парсить XML. Мой софт переводили на корейский и китайский Традосом, кое-что в strings.xml пришлось ковырять ломиком, но на 90% отработало все правильно.

А вообще - голову не грейте отдайте переводчикам - пусть они голову ломают, а машинный перевод это маразм. У меня даже статистика есть по странам кто как переводил, так народ и качает. Скажем, на итальянский переводил живой макаронник, так там и закачек больше всех, на французский переводила тётка с нижегородской губернии - закачек почти нет.

Comment: Судя по ответам придётся нанять переводчиков на top5 языков. Но что делать с каким-нибудь кхмерским (да, такой существует)?! По моему лучше что-то, чем ничего (не все кхмеры знают инглишь)

Comment: Нанимайте переводчиков. Касаемо кхмерского - при уровне доходов в Камбодже $100 в год, ваш продукт там не скоро будет востребован :)

Comment: Поскольку values-kh/string.xml никому мешать не будет, пусть живёт :)

Comment: Согласен с @Barmaley - неча мозг парить. Делайте пяток-десяток переводов на основные языки и это охватит 90% потенциальные аудитории. Реализовывать переводы на остальные, малораспространенные языки потребует слишком много усилий, выхлоп будет никакой, а качество перевода - низкое. Лучше чтоб программа была незабагованная и имела цельный, грамотный интерфейс на английском. Иначе, плохой перевод может отпугнуть потенциальных пользователей.

Comment: Еще хочу сказать, что если уж добавлять кхмерский, то почему не замахнуться на все языки? Якутский, например, добавить. Или язык коми. Чем они хуже? На мой взгляд ответ в количестве носителей языка. И в том, что носители таких языков, знают какой-либо второй, более общепринятый язык. Еще пример - финны практически все понимают шведский, он у них второй государственный, ну, и в школе им худо-бедно преподают английский. Вот и думайте стоит ли ради охвата 5 млн. человек тратить столько сил.

Comment: Проблема с малыми языками еще и в том, что нет ведь общепринятых кодовых страниц. Скажем все тот же якутский: есть несколько конкурирующих codepage, каждый из которых продвигает некая группа, но нет общепринятого стандарта принятого на уровне ISO или хотя бы ГОСТ.

Answer (score 5):

ИМХО, автоматический перевод — это неуважение к пользователям.

Писал однажды разработчикам одного приложения о недопереводе — сказали, что если я могу помочь, то я могу сделать это на [Crowdin](http://crowdin.net/). Не знаю, как разработчикам, но переводчикам достаточно удобно. Для Open Source проектов — бесплатно, для всех остальных — цены [здесь](http://crowdin.net/pricing). 10 дней триала. Есть и другие подобные проекты, стоит только поискать. Ну или сделать свой для себя :-)

Comment: +! Лучше уж на хорошем английском продавать в усурийским индийцам, чем на непойми что, но на их диалекте. Ибо китайские чеки типа "стелька потная один запарник" вызовут большее раздражение чем адекватный перевод на интернациональный язык.

Comment: +1, тем более для андройда всегда можно найти помощников  на 4pda and XDA которые помогут и перевести и баги отловить ...